# Enum расширений файлов

Tags: c#, .net

Всем добрый день. Есть проблема, в программе проверяю каждый выбранный формат файла, но хардкодить формат в кавычках не хочется, некрасиво. Есть возможность создать перечисление этих форматов, чтобы они были изначально там определены? Или может другое решение для этого есть? Формат проверяется таким планом, сначала  идет точка потом формат: `.mp3`, `.wav`

```
switch (System.IO.Path.GetExtension(names[i]))
{
    case ".mp3":
    case ".wav":                         
        // something
        break;
    default:
        MessageBox.Show($"File {songName[i]} is not in the correct format!");
        break;
}
```

Comment: Массивы и проверка на вхождение?

Comment: Обратите внимание на регистр букв: расширение может быть `WAV`, `wav`, `Wav` и т. п.

Comment: @AlexanderPetrov хорошее замечание, поправил ответ.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Один из вариантов создать перечисление по разновидности файлов, где разновидность отвечат за способ обработки файла в вашем `switch`.

```cs
public enum FileCategory
{
    Unknown,
    Audio,
    Video,
    Image,
    Text
}
```

И далее создать словарь. Значения этого словаря можно хранить даже в файле с данными и загружать в приложение при запуске. Тогда для его модификации не придется менять код приложения.

```cs
private readonly Dictionary<string, FileCategory> _fileCategories = new Dictionary<string, FileCategory>
{
    { "mp3", FileCategory.Audio },
    { "wav", FileCategory.Audio },
    { "mp4", FileCategory.Video },
    { "avi", FileCategory.Video },
    { "png", FileCategory.Image },
    { "jpg", FileCategory.Image }
}
```

Затем можно создать метод, который расширение преобразует в значение перечисления

```cs
public FileCategory GetFileCategory(string extension)
{
    return _fileCategories.TryGetValue(extension.Trim('.').ToLower(), out FileCategory category) ? category : FileCategory.Unknown;
}
```

Далее можно использовать

```cs
switch (GetFileCategory(Path.GetExtension(names[i])))
{
    case FileCategory.Audio:                      
        // something
        break;
    case FileCategory.Video:                      
        // something
        break;
    case FileCategory.Unknown:
        MessageBox.Show($"File {songName[i]} is not in the correct format!");
        break;
}
```

Само собой, я понял, что вам нужно только зарегистрировать известные расширения аудио файлов, но показал расширенную версию, чтобы вам было проще понять, на что способен данный подход.